# Elmah: How do I log form post data?

Tags: forms, elmah, error-logging

Is there a way to log the post request data in ELMAH?

I am getting error emails, and while the error log contains the URL, request method, etc, I am not seeing the actual POST data.

For example,

Here is a sample
Actual request: /bep/KotexCode/GetCode?stickerCode=1234532

But, the log only shows the request url and not the variable stickerCode.
Thanks!

**Edit**
Sorry, I should have checked the project website, but it looks like this feature was requested.
http://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/detail?id=164

Comment: NB: if you want JSON see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686466/elmah-how-to-get-json-http-request-body-from-error-report/8741276#8741276

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[This was also addressed](http://groups.google.com/group/elmah/msg/ee8417243bd74c8b) in the [ELMAH discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/elmah), quoted below verbatim:

> ELMAH actually does log all the form
>   data. It is not displayed alongside
>   server variables by default when you
>   look at the error detail page but can
>   be dug out of the raw XML view from
>   the very same page. The form data,
>   however, is also not included in
>   e-mails.
>
> The real reason for leaving out the
>   display of form data was to avoid
>   bloat and noise from a lot of ASP.NET
>   applications with very large view
>   states (hundreds of KB). Also, some
>   forms include lots of HTML in textarea
>   fields (especially CMS systems) that
>   could also lead to large amounts of
>   noise. In the absence of a single good
>   solution that fit all sizes, the
>   problem has been left as being outside
>   the scope of ELMAH (though still open
>   for discussion). If someone needs to
>   display FORM data, a custom error
>   detail page is very quick to code up.

Comment: Thank you! At least I can look at the error log XML files to see what's going on.

Comment: Cool. So, I was able to get the form data by looking at the error XML file. Thanks again!

Comment: Isn't logging all form post data a security issue?

Comment: Excellent, this is great to know.

Comment: @MartinS No more than logging the server variables (which includes your login cookie etc). Anyway I don't see how its' a security issue as in a correctly configured setup, only the website developer has any access to Elmah.

Comment: @NickG Login forms will contain plaintext passwords. Payment forms will include plaintext credit card and CVV data. This is a security issue.

Comment: This gets included in emails as of writing this comment.